# What is BS"D in Mac OS X and iOS Internals?

Tags: bsd

I just received my copy of Mac OS X and iOS Internals, and there is something a little strange:

`Chapter 13: BS"D: The BSD Layer`

Is there an explanation for the extra quote ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's not a typo. And it's not an allusion to Jewish roots, though the origin *is* Jewish. BS"D is yiddish for with the help of a greater power (as in, God). The idea in this chapter is that OS X goes to where it did with the help of a greater foundation, BSD's. It also ties in to "On the Shoulders of Giants", which is Chapter 3, which is the user-mode mirror image of that chapter.

All the chapters have double titles. Makes for a more interesting read :-)

Comment: and check the book's news feed (http://newosxbook.com/rss.php) - The author clarified this personally there..

Comment: That's interesting. I had not noticed the double titles - but that's obvious when you look at the chapters titles sequentially. And somehow today I couldn't resist to buy "On the shoulders Giants" when I saw it.

Answer (score -1):

BSD is an acronym for Berkeley Software Distribution and shouldn't carry the ". Probably a typo.